# How to catch a redirection RedirectResponse from Vuejs and redirect

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to make a payment with [laravel/cashier-mollie](https://github.com/laravel/cashier-mollie). I use only vuejs for the front-end.

Here is my controller :

```
public function __invoke(string $plan)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();

        $name = ucfirst($plan) . ' membership';

        if(!$user->subscribed($name, $plan)) {

            $result = $user->newSubscriptionViaMollieCheckout($name, $plan)->create();

            if(is_a($result, RedirectResponse::class)) {
                return $result; // Redirect to Mollie checkout
            }

            return response()->json([
               'status' => 'Félicitation, vous êtes inscrit au ' . $plan . ' plan'
            ]);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'Vous êtes déjà inscrit au ' . $plan . ' plan'
        ]);
    }
```

I should normally be redirected to an internal Mollie page to make the payment. As I use Vuejs, I'm not.

In chrome, I get a good xhr. When I copy / paste the link into the browser, I'm redirecting to Mollie.

[image]

I tried this, but the answer only returns empty items :

```
return response()->json($result);
```

Response :

```
{"headers":{},"original":null,"exception":null}
```

How can I get the redirect link so I can redirect the user to Mollie with Vuejs?

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing XHR request and your server sends Redirect response, then it redirects this XHR request, not the browser itself.

You should either respond with some JSON that contains redirect URL that could be used in your client to redirect browser to (not recommended), or don't send XHR request at all, and just send client's browser on URL that will be redirected later.